# Best practice to set environment variables in package.json scripts or Dockerfile?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, dockerfile, package.json

In the process of containerizing a react app using Docker, I have these below scripts in my `package.json` file. QA and Stage have different .env variables.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f ./config/.env.qa react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f ./config/.env.qa react-scripts build",
  },
```

The issue is that the .env path in the `build` script needs to be manually updated to `./config/.env.qa` or `./config/.env.staging` depending on deploying to qa or stage. I'm looking for a common practice to make the process automatic. Now sure how it should be done?

The Dockerfile is like below

```
FROM node:16.18.0 as build
RUN node -v
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN echo $WORKDIR
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN ls -ltr /usr/src/app/build/
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build/ .
EXPOSE 80
CMD nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```